# System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5 => Where is the data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-ce

I am trying to update a System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5 database. The trick is that these databases are installed on client's PCs and we need them to upload the database to a web site, the web site then manages the data, then they download the updated database to the client. (Not sure if this is even possible)

Where is the "database" for a System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5 based windows application? (In access it would be the *.mdb file)

Comment: Where would it be kept by a PC program that installs to the c:\program files folder?

Comment: I believe it would be `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` so the file should be inside `c:\Program Files\{ApplicationFolder}`

Comment: It can be in any location on the PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the *.sdf file in the roaming folder